# Dynamic Variables Jekyll Liquid

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I would like to use dynamic variables for my jekyll + liquid installation.
I want to dynamically access the _config.yml file using the dynamic variable
names.

It is best explained with an example:

**Page:**

```
---
layout: default
title: title_homepage
---
```

**Default Layout:**

```
{{ site.locales[site.default_locale].page.title }}
```

**_config.yml:**

```
default_locale: "en"

locales:
  en:
    title_homepage: "This is my homepage title!"
  pirate:
    title_homepage: "Yaaawwwr. Homepage title."
```

So how can I access the _config.yml with a dynamic variable name?

Comment: To make sure I'm clear. You're '_config.yml' file will always be named exactly that. To make the change you'll update the 'default_locale' variable inside '_config.yml' from 'en' to 'pirate'. At that point, when you run jekyll, you want the output in your default layout to show "Yaaawwwr. Homepage title." instead of "This is my homepage title!". Is that accurate?

Comment: Hi Alan, yep. that is correct. Then I'll generate one _site for en, another one for _pirate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title that you want to pull is form the site config. Not the page itself. All you need to do is change the call in your Default Layout listing to this:

```
{{ site.locales[site.default_locale].title_homepage }}
```

When you set `default_locale: "en"` the output will be "This is my homepage title!". When you update the _config.yml file to `default_locale: "pirate"`, the output will be "Yaaawwwr. Homepage title." I've tested this on Jekyll 0.11.2 and it works as expected.

Comment: thanks for the idea. but this would still leave me with the problem that I have to define multiple layouts for multiple pages. I would like to define the page title inside the Page. Option 1: Translate the page title inside the YAML front matter of the page, or option 2: dynamically translate it in the default layout.

Comment: Ah. I thought you were looking for a global title that was defined in the _config.yml file. I think this question is still useful. My suggestion is that we leave this one as is and create a new question that focuses on using a setting in _config.yml to change titles that are defined individually in each page/post.

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750755/jekyll-liquid-accessing-config-yml-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll is a static website generator, its unable to usa a variable. But I guess for locale it self, there are one simple solution.

Follow this file structure (or something like that):

```
root
  - _include
    home.html
  - _layout
    default.html
  - en
    index.html
  - pirate
    index.html
  index.html
```

That simple, now use include for {{content}} and create simple files with variables and one single line {% include index.html %}

**_include/index.html :**

```
<h1>{{page.title}}</h1>
```

**en/index.html :**

```
---
layout: default
title: "This is my homepage title!"
---
{% include home.html %}
```

**pirate/index.html :**

```
---
layout: default
title: "Yaaawwwr. Homepage title."
---
{% include home.html %}
```

So... that is it.

Now create a page variable to handle locale urls for each page....

I hope this help.