# Jekyll Liquid - accessing _config.yml dynamically

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

For internationalizing my app I need to be able to dynamically access entries in a YAML file.

It is best explained with an example:

**Page:**

```
---
layout: default
title: title_homepage
---
```

This will then allow access to the title_homepage variable in the Default Layout Template:

**Default Layout:**

page.title = "title_homepage"

Now normally I would access my _config.yml file like this:

```
{{ site.locales[site.default_locale].variable }}
```

However, now for this to work, I need to access the _config.yml with the value of page.title. This will not work:

```
{{ site.locales[site.default_locale].page.title }}
```

I need the following (pseudo code):

```
{{ site.locales[site.default_locale].#{value of page.title}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the way your vars are set, it would be something alog the lines of

```
{{ site.locales[site.default_locale][page.title] }}
```

The thing is, *... I don't really see the point of doing this*. Let's say your page is the english page. The locale should then be defined within the page, and so should your title!

```
---
locale: en
title: My Wonderful Page
---
```

Which you can retrieve with `{{ page.title }}` ...

What could be the point of putting the title into the `_config.yml` file?

(edit) well unless you want to access `page.title` when in another page/post, in this case you have no choice but to put it into `_config.yml`.

Comment: You rock. This works. I didn't know you could access the array like that with the page.title variable. I can now define the locale once in the _config.yml file. Then, on each page i can set a custom title, it will check my config.yml with the locale for the translation, then use that as title. epic.