# Dynamic variable name Jekyll / Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to use a variable as a name of another variable.

```
{% assign key = string[0] %}
{% assign {{key}} = string[1] %}
```

Is this possible? If not, is there any alternative that I could use that would let me achieve similar things as this variable?

---

I'm not trying to access a variable, I'm trying to assign it, so this isn't a duplicate of [Dynamic Variables Jekyll Liquid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674846/dynamic-variables-jekyll-liquid).

Comment: Is it possible that the capture tag could be used here?

Comment: I think capture does not work here... this is about the name of the variable.

Comment: I am trying to override a jekyll default variable. In this case `page.title`. But I am not able to assign it a new value. Is this possible in some other way?